# Who owns returned string from _bstr_t::wchar_t*, _bstr_t::char* operators?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, com, memory-leaks, bstr

`_bstr_t::wchar_t*, _bstr_t::char*` [operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btdzb8eb.aspx) return string of different types.

Do I need to `delete` or `free` them? using which function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After stepping the implementation using debugger, my conclusion is that there is no need to manually `delete`/`free` the returned string. The lifetime of the returned string is managed by `_bstr_t` internally.

See the following snippets from the implementation:

```
// Extract a const char_t*
//
inline _bstr_t::operator const char*() const throw(_com_error)
{
    return (m_Data != NULL) ? m_Data->GetString() : NULL;
}

inline const char* _bstr_t::Data_t::GetString() const throw(_com_error)
{
    if (m_str == NULL) {
        m_str = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(m_wstr);

        if (m_str == NULL && m_wstr != NULL) {
            _com_issue_error(E_OUTOFMEMORY);
        }
    }

    return m_str;
}

inline void _bstr_t::Data_t::_Free() throw()
{
    if (m_wstr != NULL) {
        ::SysFreeString(m_wstr);
    }

    if (m_str != NULL) {
        delete [] m_str;
    }
}
```

It is also okay to use unnamed `_bstr_t` as follows because `_bstr_t` instance is destroyed ***after*** the constructor of `CString` has finished.

```
CString abc((LPCTSTR)_bstr_t(OLESTR("ABC")));
AfxMessageBox(abc);
```